# С помощью beautifulsoup извлечь ИНН и КПП по отдельности

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

[image: Как с помощью beautifulsoup лучше (правильнее) извлечь ИНН и КПП в данном случае? По отдельности.]

Как с помощью beautifulsoup лучше (правильнее) извлечь ИНН и КПП в данном случае? По отдельности.

Comment: Контрольные числа посчитай и будет понятно где инн

Comment: инн - 12 чисел, кпп -9

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin 12 - у физических лиц. У юридических - 10. Как на скрине.

Comment: @Эникейщик да вы правы. Главное что они по длине отличаются )

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<p> == $0
<b>инн </b>
5001067335
<b>КПП </b>
500101001
<span class="text--bold">Регион: </span>
<a target="_blank" href="/poisk/region/moskovskaya-oblast/">Московская область</a>
</p>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'lxml')
_, inn, _, kpp = [x for x in soup.stripped_strings][1:-2]
print(inn, kpp)

5001067335 500101001
```